# Brute force password VBA

Tags: string, vba, brute-force

I'm trying to workout how one could cycle through all possibilities of a string but i doesn't seem to be going very well.

I have so far put a set of characters into an array but I cant for the life of me get my head around how I can make it work. I have got this far but my brain cannot seem to get round it.

Can any one shed any light of the proper way to do this and possibly pseudo code so I can create my own.

```
Function passwordGenerator(length As Integer)
    Dim characters() As String
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim t As Integer

    Dim oldpassword As String
    Dim newcharacter As String

    ReDim Preserve characters(1)

    For x = 48 To 90
        ReDim Preserve characters(UBound(characters) + 1)
        characters(UBound(characters) - 1) = VBA.Chr(x)
    Next x
    y = 1

        Do

            For x = 1 To length
            oldpassword = generateBlank(x)
            p = 1
                For t = 1 To p
                newpassword = WorksheetFunction.Replace(oldpassword, t, 1, characters(y))
                    For y = 1 To UBound(characters)
                        newpassword = WorksheetFunction.Replace(oldpassword, p, 1, characters(y))
                        Debug.Print newpassword
                        p = p + 1
                    Next y
                Next t
            Next x

        Loop


    End Function



Function generateBlank(length As Integer)

Dim x As Integer

For x = 1 To length
    generateBlank = generateBlank & "A"
Next x

End Function
```

EDIT:::

I have edited my code but this way i have to know the length and that does not create an effective algorithm? Any help?

```
Function passwordGenerator()
Dim characters() As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim p As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim w As Integer
Dim e As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim u As Integer

Dim oldpassword As String
Dim newcharacter As String

ReDim Preserve characters(1)

For x = 48 To 90
    ReDim Preserve characters(UBound(characters) + 1)
    characters(UBound(characters) - 1) = VBA.Chr(x)
Next x
y = 1

oldpassword = generateBlank(3)
        For x = 1 To UBound(characters)
            oldpassword = WorksheetFunction.Replace(oldpassword, 1, 1, characters(x))
            For t = 1 To UBound(characters)
                oldpassword = WorksheetFunction.Replace(oldpassword, 2, 1, characters(t))
                For y = 1 To UBound(characters)
                    oldpassword = WorksheetFunction.Replace(oldpassword, 3, 1, characters(y))
                    For q = 1 To UBound(characters)
                        oldpassword = WorksheetFunction.Replace(oldpassword, 4, 1, characters(q))
                        For w = 1 To UBound(characters)
                            oldpassword = WorksheetFunction.Replace(oldpassword, 5, 1, characters(w))
                            Debug.Print oldpassword
                            DoEvents
                        Next w
                    Next q
                Next y
            Next t
        Next x
End Function
```

Comment: Are we to assume you are going to use your powers for good? ;)

Comment: Well i'm sure it would be a slow process if i was i'm aware it is a slow process, but alas no. I'm on a journey of intellectual discovery. haha

Comment: Are you trying to generate all possible passwords with `n` length using a predefined set of characters?

Comment: Are you trying to get the password used to lock a workbook using password protection? The title would suggest so but the code would suggest you are generating possible password combinations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have edited the code in JA72's answer to provide a more comprehensive technique for brute forcing the "Restrict Editing" password.  I removed the `array` and `ReDim` portions, and combined it all into one sub.  The problem with JA's method is, while it works for the character set of `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789` for 4-character passwords ([26+26+10]^4 = 14,776,336 possibilities), it does not work with a 5-character password ([26+26+10]^5 = 916,132,832 possibilities). The array functions in the original code cause a 32-bit Office application to immediately run out of memory when trying 5-character passwords or beyond.  I also noticed memory usage climbing as it iterated through 14 million possibilities with the original code, whereas memory usage stays flat with the code below.

This example specifically targets Word's `ActiveDocument.Unprotect` method.  It's simple enough to change the section that attempts to use the password to whatever Office object model suits your needs.

This code worked for me after several hours and about 400 million password attempts.  I feel it was likely a hash collision versus the actual password, but I'll take what works.

If you want to see the output work before you commit to several hours of CPU to this, there are a few things included for convenience.  This is explained in code comments as well.

- Set the number of iterations by editing the `n` variable.
- Change the first loop `For i = 1 to m` to `For i = 1 to n` to loop only so many times instead of all possible times.
- Turn on the output by uncommenting the line `If i Mod showEvery = 0 Then Debug.Print i, pw` line.
- If you want to see every password: leave `showEvery` set to 1, otherwise choose a different number to see every nth password.
- Comment the section that actually tries the password against `ActiveDocument.Unprotect` and checks for errors.  It's marked in the code with comments.

---

```
Sub GetPassword()

Dim s As Integer, totalChars As Integer, j As Long  'GeneratePassword loop vars
Dim gpi As Long           'GeneratePassword index
Dim characters As String  'characters that can be part of the password.
Dim pw As String          'password attempt string

characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
totalChars = Len(characters)

Dim i As Double           'count integer
Dim n As Double           'number of interations to complete (if active)
Dim pwLen As Integer      'length of password
Dim m As Double           'number of permutations
Dim showEvery As Integer  'show multiples of this in debug log

pwLen = 5                 'password length
m = totalChars ^ pwLen    'number of potential combinations of characters for the length
n = 1000                  'number of loop iterations if you don't want all of them.
showEvery = 1             'use 1 here to show every password.  10000 shows every 10,000th password, etc...

On Error Resume Next      'no need to invoke an error handler, just check the Err.Number
For i = 1 To m  'use "1 to n" if you want to test a certain number or "1 to m" if you want try all combinations.
    pw = vbNullString
    gpi = i     'assign GeneratePassword loop integer our loop integer
    'GeneratePassword loop
    For s = 1 To pwLen
        j = ((gpi - 1) Mod totalChars) + 1
        pw = Mid(characters, j, 1) & pw
        gpi = (gpi - j) \ totalChars + 1
    Next s

    'writes out if uncommented and it's the right i. comment out once you're sure of the output.
    'If i Mod showEvery = 0 Then Debug.Print i, pw

    'try the password to unprotect the document, comment if just testing passwords in Immediate window
    ActiveDocument.Unprotect password:=pw
    If Err.Number <> 5485 Then
        MsgBox "Unexpected Error Code: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & pw
    End If
    If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType = wdNoProtection Then
        MsgBox "Unprotected with password: " & vbCrLf & pw
        Debug.Print "Unprotect Password:  " & pw
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'end trying the password.

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want:

```
Public Function GeneratePassword(ByVal index As Long, ByVal pw_len As Byte, ByRef characters As String) As String
    ' Convert string 'characters' into array of characters in 'dict'
    Dim s As Integer, n As Integer
    n = Len(characters)
    Dim pw As String
    pw = vbNullString
    Dim j As Long, base As Long
    base = n
    For s = 1 To pw_len
        j = ((index - 1) Mod n) + 1
        pw = Mid(characters, j, 1) & pw
        index = (index - j) \ n + 1
    Next s
    GeneratePassword = pw
End Function


Public Sub TestPwGen()
    Dim i As Long, pw() As String, abc As String
    abc = "ABC"
    Dim n As Integer, l As Integer, m As Long
    ' password length 4, generate 18 passwords
    l = 4: m = Len(abc) ^ l 
    n = 18
    ReDim pw(1 To n)
    For i = 1 To n 'Total is m
        pw(i) = GeneratePassword(i, l, abc)
        Debug.Print pw(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Result:

```
AAAA
AAAB
AAAC
AABA
AABB
AABC
AACA
AACB
AACC
ABAA
ABAB
ABAC
ABBA
ABBB
ABBC
ABCA
ABCB
ABCC
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for me, this problem stuck in my head until I had to write down my solution. @ja72's solution is more elegant I think, but I'll list mine for the sake of contributing another way of doing it.

```
Option Explicit

Function passwordGenerator()
    Dim characters() As String
    Dim loASCII As Integer
    Dim hiASCII As Integer
    Dim numASCII As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    loASCII = 48
    hiASCII = 90
    numASCII = hiASCII - loASCII
    ReDim characters(numASCII)
    For i = loASCII To hiASCII
        characters(i - loASCII) = VBA.Chr(i)
    Next i

    PermutationsOn characters, 2

End Function

Sub PermutationsOn(ByRef charSet() As String, numPlaces As Integer)
    '--- Generates every possible combination of characters from the given
    '    character set for an n-place string
    '    Inputs: charSet   - string array of all possible values
    '            numPlaces - integer noting how many characters in the output string
    Dim chars() As String
    Dim thisString As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim t As Long
    Dim numInCharSet As Integer
    Dim start As Integer
    Dim placevalues() As Integer

    '--- this array is used as a set of indexes into the character set, the
    '    indexes will range from charSet(0) to charSet(last), "counting" as
    '    in a base-n number, where n = len(charSet)+1
    ReDim placevalues(1 To numPlaces) As Integer
    ReDim chars(1 To numPlaces)

    start = LBound(charSet)
    numInCharSet = UBound(charSet)
    '--- initialize the arrays
    For i = 1 To numPlaces
        placevalues(i) = 0
    Next i
    For i = 1 To numPlaces
        chars(i) = charSet(start)
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Permutations on a " & numPlaces & "-place value from a character set"
    Debug.Print "Character set (len=" & numInCharSet + 1 & "): '" & ConcatToString(charSet) & "'"

    '--- build the first string...
    t = 1
    thisString = BuildStringFromSet(placevalues, charSet)
    Debug.Print t & ": " & thisString
    Do Until IncrementValues(placevalues, charSet)
        '--- build the current string...
        thisString = BuildStringFromSet(placevalues, charSet)
        t = t + 1
        Debug.Print t & ": " & thisString
    Loop
    Debug.Print "Total strings generated: " & t
End Sub

Function IncrementValues(ByRef placevalues() As Integer, ByRef placeRange() As String) As Boolean
    '--- views the placeValues array as a "single" number with a numeric base of "numInRange+1"
    Dim highestValueReached As Boolean
    Dim numPlaces As Integer
    Dim numInRange As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    numPlaces = UBound(placevalues)
    numInRange = UBound(placeRange)
    highestValueReached = False
    For i = 1 To numPlaces
        If placevalues(i) <> numInRange Then
            placevalues(i) = placevalues(i) + 1
            Exit For
        Else
            If i = numPlaces Then
                highestValueReached = True
                Exit For
            Else
                placevalues(i) = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    IncrementValues = highestValueReached
End Function

Function BuildStringFromSet(ByRef placevalues() As Integer, ByRef charSet() As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim finalString As String
    finalString = ""
    For i = UBound(placevalues) To 1 Step -1
        finalString = finalString & charSet(placevalues(i))
    Next i
    BuildStringFromSet = finalString
End Function

Function ConcatToString(chars() As String) As String
    Dim finalString As String
    Dim j As Integer
    finalString = ""
    For j = LBound(chars) To UBound(chars)
        finalString = finalString & chars(j)
    Next j
    ConcatToString = finalString
End Function
```

With the output results:

```
Permutations on a 5-place value from a character set
Character set (len=43): '0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
1: 00000
2: 00001
3: 00002
4: 00003
...
147008441: ZZZZX
147008442: ZZZZY
147008443: ZZZZZ
Total strings generated: 147008443
```

Comment: How long did it take you to run?

Comment: Running on an Intel i7 CPU @ 2.93GHz, my results (with the `debug.print` statements commented out) averaged:  2-place string=3.21ms, 3-place string=81.72ms, 4-place string=3.74sec, 5-place string=181.1sec. Of course, writing to the screen with debug.print, or to spreadsheet cells, or to a file will also slow the process.

Answer (score 1):

This could probably be improved but a simple idea is to treat the characters separately and roll over like an odometer would. BTW, I used one-based indexes for the array but zero-based for the individual digits.

```
Public Sub PasswordGen()
Const MaxDigit = 42
Const MaxLoops = MaxDigit * MaxDigit * MaxDigit * MaxDigit * MaxDigit
Dim places(10) As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim digit As Integer
Dim password As String

counter = 0
Do While counter < MaxLoops
    password = Chr(places(5) + 48) & Chr(places(4) + 48) & Chr(places(3) + 48) & Chr(places(2) + 48) & Chr(places(5) + 48)
    'Debug.Print password
    counter = counter + 1
    digit = 1
    Do While digit < 10
        places(digit) = places(digit) + 1
        If places(digit) = MaxDigit Then
            places(digit) = 0
            digit = digit + 1
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
Loop
End Sub
```

You could also do away with the counter and just exit the loop when the digit equals 11 because of a carry out of the tenth place (an overflow). I doubt you'll actually let it run that long anyway.

Comment: That's what I get for posting without actually testing it. It seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

I actually came up with an answer my own answer. It came to me at work today.

```
Public characters() As String
Public oldpassword As String

Function passwordGenerator1(maxLength)

Dim x As Integer, newcharacter As String
ReDim Preserve characters(1)

'set characters in array
    For x = 48 To 90
        ReDim Preserve characters(UBound(characters) + 1)
        characters(UBound(characters) - 1) = VBA.Chr(x)
    Next x

'loop through all lengths
    For x = 1 To maxLength
        oldpassword = generateBlank(x)
        changeCharacter 1, x
    Next x
End Function
```

-

```
Function changeCharacter(characterPos, length As Integer)

    For x = 1 To UBound(characters)
        If characterPos <> length Then changeCharacter characterPos + 1, length
        oldpassword = WorksheetFunction.Replace(oldpassword, characterPos, 1, characters(x))
        Debug.Print oldpassword
        DoEvents
    Next x

End Function
```

-

```
Function generateBlank(length As Integer)

Dim x As Integer

    For x = 1 To length
        generateBlank = generateBlank & "A"
    Next x

End Function
```